# Using subtotal formula in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA procedure that pulls some data from a database, dumps it into a worksheet, adds a header row an converts all that to a table. That bit works fine. The data returned has an indeterminate number of rows. What I need to do as add a summary row at the end. I was looking to account for the unknown table length by using the subtotal function: `SUBTOTAL(109,[5 year total])`, for example.

The problem is I am getting a

`Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

This code works

`Range(upperleft).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 6).Value = "Test cash 5 year total"`

where as this code throws the error

`Range(upperleft).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 6).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[cash: 5 year total])"`

the `upperleft` variable is the top left cell of the table. It seems to be something to do with the string I am using for the formula/value since if I try to set the formula to a value like this

`Range(upperleft).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 6).Value= "=SUBTOTAL(109,[cash: 5 year total])"`

I get the same error

Comment: You seem to be missing the table name from the formula.

Comment: Thank you. Let me look into that. I used the macro recorder for the syntax of the subtotal so it might have made some wrong assumptions.

Comment: The formula you have should work if it's in a Totals Row that is part of the table but, if not, you need to include the table name: `=SUBTOTAL(109,Table1[cash: 5 year total])` for example.

Comment: Adding the table reference was the ticket. If you post your comment as an proposed answer, I will accept it. I want you to get credit. Thank you so much, Rory. The information I was able to find on subtotal did not call out the table reference and excel doesn't do it by default in the recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have should work as long as it is in a Totals Row that is part of the table but, if not, you need to include the table name:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,Table1[cash: 5 year total])
```

for example

Comment: This was a great catch. I was trusting to Macro Recorder to provide the details I needed. It did not. I am not a dedicate VBA developer. Also, this was great because all the documentation that I had found online did not mention referencing the table name in the subtotal formula and, of course, the error message was not helpful. Thanks Rory!